# Map.insert prompting an error in Haskell without reason

Tags: dictionary, haskell, compiler-errors

This is the function I am using:

```
threeWordFunction :: [String] -> Map.Map String [String] -> String
threeWordFunction [x, y, z] orbitingData = do
     Map.insert z [x, y] orbitingData
     ""
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
src\MyLib.hs:40:6: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Map.Map String' with `[]'
      Expected type: [[String]]
        Actual type: Map.Map String [String]
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: Map.insert z [x, y] orbitingData
      In the expression:
        do Map.insert z [x, y] orbitingData
           ""
      In an equation for `threeWordFunction':
          threeWordFunction [x, y, z] orbitingData
            = do Map.insert z [x, ....] orbitingData
                 ""
   |
40 |      Map.insert z [x, y] orbitingData
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've tried a whole bunch of fixes but found nothing that could cause this error. The function is just trying to add the strings to the map, nothing fancy. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the function meant to achieve ? Which monad is your `do` construct supposed to belong to ?

Comment: You are using `do`, as if you were working inside a monad, but you are not. The result type is `String` which is `[] Char`, so GHC thinks you want to work in the `[]` monad, and expects a `do` block of `[] something` entries. The `Map`-valued insert then triggers the type error. You likely need no monads for this, and no `do` is needed. Can you explain, in plain English, the algorithm you want to implement in your code? (Also note that `insert` does not modify a map, it builds a new one with the additional value.)

Comment: I'm simply trying to create a new map, that has the values inserted. And then return a blank string for now. At some point the string will contain data but I'm stuck on this part for now

Comment: If you want to create a new map, you need to *return* that new map, so the result type of your function would have to be `Map String [String]` and not `String`. This is Haskell, so you cannot *alter* an existing map object. Check the [specs of Map.insert](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html)

Comment: I understand that, the new map that is being created is going to be used further in this function. It isn't meant to be returned. The string is meant to be returned

Comment: Use `threeWordFunction [x, y, z] orbitingData = let newMap = Map.insert z [x, y] orbitingData in ""`. Of course, until you actually use `newMap` the insertion is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

As some contributors says, the `do` is the problem.
However, let me try to decompose what you want (as I can see) and what you do.

```
threeWordFunction :: [String] -> Map.Map String [String] -> String
```

declares the type of your function. It is what you plan to do. With a list of `String` and a `Map` you want to provide a `String`. If I read this, in Haskell, I will deduce that you probably want to use the `Map` to extract something useful to build a `String`. Indeed, the only output of your function is a `String`. Since the `Map` is not an output any modification will be "lost".

When I read what you want to do, you claimed that you want to insert a value in the `Map`. So I suppose that you want to output your resulting `Map`. And here I can deduce your first error : you think with side effect. I suppose that you wanted to modify the `Map` inside your function, and you've expected that the Map will be modified outside the function. But it is not how Haskell works. This is how most languages with imperative features works.

So to **do** this you want to use a `do` word. The state of mind behind this is to provide a sequence of instruction like in a C-block with curly braces. And this is wrong. In Haskell, the `do` word is syntaxic sugar and points the fact that you are in a monad... So the result of your computation will probably be a monad. But this is not what the function type said. So the compiler produces an error.

**What can you do to be consistent with your type**

Considering the type, a solution will be the one provide by Chi.

```
threeWordFunction [x, y, z] orbitingData = let newMap = Map.insert z [x, y] orbitingData in ""
```

The compiler will complain no more. You build a new Map `newMap` that is modify the way you want. And you provide the `String` `""` as an output. However, the `newMap` will never be reachable outside your function. So the insert is useless.

**What can you do to achieve your need**

Change the type... The type in Haskell provide a specification that clearly defines the expected valid solutions (more or less).

So you can want something that explicitly provide a Map.

```
threeWordFunction :: [String] -> Map.Map String [String] -> Map.Map String [String]
```

or a Map and a String

```
threeWordFunction :: [String] -> Map.Map String [String] -> (Map.Map String [String], String)
```

You can also use monad like State but it may be too much for your level.

Considering the new type, you can now return an entity that is what you need.

```
threeWordFunction :: [String] -> Map.Map String [String] -> (Map.Map String [String], String)
threeWordFunction [x, y, z] orbitingData = 
    let newMap = Map.insert z [x, y] orbitingData 
    in (newMap, "")
```

NB if you always want to provide a `""` as a String, this probably indicates that you don't need it.

Hope this will help you understand the problem.

Comment: It sounds like they intend to modify the map and then use the modified map to produce the string. They just haven't gotten around to the second part yet.

Comment: May be... It could be the right expected behavior. In this case, the solution is to temporarily correct the type to be consistant with the expected one. Then work on the String after that.